# iOS 13 Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: firebase, webrtc, ios13

I've been looking for a solution to an error that I couldn't solve since in firebase it doesn't give me any information.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1aa0b2a48 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1a9dd9fa4 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1a9fb4e88 +[_CFXNotificationTokenRegistration keyCallbacks]
3  Foundation                     0x1aa3ea6c4 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  FrontBoardServices             0x1af21ba4c -[FBSSerialQueue assertOnQueue]
5  FrontBoardServices             0x1af1d0ec8 -[FBSSceneImpl updateClientSettings:withTransitionContext:]
6  FrontBoardServices             0x1af1d1130 -[FBSSceneImpl updateClientSettingsWithTransitionBlock:]
7  FrontBoardServices             0x1af1d1038 -[FBSSceneImpl updateClientSettingsWithBlock:]
8  UIKitCore                      0x1adcb87f4 -[FBSScene(UIApp) updateUIClientSettingsWithBlock:]
9  UIKitCore                      0x1adda2508 -[UIDevice(Private) _enableDeviceOrientationEvents:]
10 UIKitCore                      0x1adda31a4 -[UIDevice beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]
11 WebRTC                         0x105476898 (Falta)
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a9d7e610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a9d7f184 _dispatch_client_callout
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a9d2b404 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a9d2bdf8 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a9d35314 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a9dceb88 _pthread_wqthread
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a9dd1760 start_wqthread
```

This is the information I receive from Firebase. What happens is that when receiving an incoming call from my app when it is completely closed and the call is accepted it closes and gives this error, if the app is in the background or open it does not close.

Thanks for the help.